# Are the 2nd to the 5th bit of primes uniformly distributed

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

For load balancing in a project I am doing I wanted to know if the following is uniformly distributed between 0 and 15:

```
(p / 2) % 16
```

Or in C:

```
(p >> 1) & 15
```

I divide by 2 because the LSB bit is always 1 on prime.
I feel as if it should be uniform considering the Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression but I can't prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any experiments?  At the moment I cannot prove this, but it seems like you could easily generate the first few million primes and see how it pans out.

Comment: I actually did check and empirically saw that it is uniformly distributed on the first 160mil primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Prime Number Theorem on arithmetic progressions the primes in each of the eight odd residue classes mod 16 are asymptotically equal in size. There are local variations (search [prime number races] and [Linnik's theorem]) but they tend to be small compared to the total number of primes.

Dirichlet's theorem is related but not enough to prove this, so don't feel bad that you weren't able to prove it using that.